# Computing Content-MD5 HTTP header file value with c#

Tags: c#, base64

I am implementing part of a service that will be responding to HTTP requests and one of the headers I was going to support is `Content-MD5`. The [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1864.txt) states the following about `Content-MD5` calculation:

> To generate the value of the Content-MD5 field, the MD5 algorithm is
>      computed on the canonical form of the MIME entity's object.  In
>      particular, this means that the sender applies the MD5 algorithm on
>      the data immediately after conversion to canonical form, before
>      applying any content-transfer-encoding, and that the receiver also
>      applies the MD5 algorithm on the canonical form, after undoing any
>      content-transfer-encoding.  For textual data, this means the MD5
>      algorithm must be computed on data in which the canonical form for
>      newlines applies, that is, in which each newline is represented by a
>      CR-LF pair.  The canonical encoding model of MIME is described in
>      Appendix G of [1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1864.txt).
>
> The output of the MD5 algorithm is a 128 bit digest.  When viewed in
>      network byte order (big-endian order), this yields a sequence of 16
>      octets of binary data.  These 16 octets are then encoded according to
>      the base64 algorithm in order to obtain the value that is placed in
>      the Content-MD5 field.  Thus, if the application of the MD5 algorithm
>      over the raw data of a MIME entity results in a digest having the
>      (unlikely) value of "Check Integrity!", then that MIME entity's
>      header could contain the field
>
> ```
>    Content-MD5:  Q2hlY2sgSW50ZWdyaXR5IQ==
> ```

(This isn't from the HTTP RFC, but it's [referenced by it](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.15))

I'm not doing any content-transfer encoding at this stage, so this should be straightforward enough, but I'm not getting the results I was expecting:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

  //somewhere in the file...
  MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
  responseBody = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Check Integrity!");
  var hash = md5.ComputeHash(responseBody);
  string encodedHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
  //now the following is true:
  encodedHash == "nwqq6b6ua/tTDk7B5M184w=="
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code, but I did misread the RFC:

> Thus, if the application of the MD5 algorithm over the raw data of a
>   MIME entity results in a digest having the (unlikely) value of "Check
>   Integrity!" (...)

the `"Check Integrity!"` is the (unlikely) MD5 hashing **result** not the response being hashed. It is not a coincidence that the string is exactly 16 ASCII chars long.

The updated verification code behaves as expected:

```
var hash = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Check Integrity!");
Assert.AreEqual(16, hash.Count()); // true
string encodedHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
Assert.AreEqual(encodedHash, "Q2hlY2sgSW50ZWdyaXR5IQ=="); // true
```